# cron.php permissions using cpanel

Tags: web, permissions, cpanel, web-hosting, whm

Regarding public_html/crons/cron.php hosted on a cpanel instance.

We found that our clients permissions are set to 644, however, we see others post that it should be 755.

What is the Best Practice for permissions on this file?

Answer (score 0):

Permission 644 which is the default would be the Best Practice Permissions for this file.